# C# problem with file.exist statement in if else statement

Tags: c#

I’m currently doing a school project where the program uses filesystemwatcher to watch a file and copy to other folders when a file is detected. However whenever there is an update to the file it will save it as _update.txt appended to the back with a copy() function I made.

The problem is there are at times where the program renames it as update even though it’s the first instance of the file. Copy function works fine. Really appreciate it as I’m a programming newbie!!

Codes are as follows:

```
try
{
    String dest = "inputTextBox.text" + "\\";
    String fileName = e.Name;

    if (!File.Exist(dest + fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            copy("");
        }

        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    else if (File.Exist(dest + fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            copy("update.txt");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: this seems not c#.

Comment: There is no need for `if` in `else if `. Also why you have put so many try catches without even handling exceptions?

Comment: It is, but needs editing/better indexing and lacks the auxiliary functions

Comment: It is C#, but with some syntax errors, like a missing brace, a missing semicolon and try/ catch misspelling.

Comment: It can be written in one line - `copy (File.Exist (dest + fileName) ? "_update.txt" : "");`

Comment: having empty catches is a bad practice because you will not have feedback of what went wrong. Change `Catch (exception)` into `catch(Exception exc)` and inside the catch block put `Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);`

Comment: Thanks guys for the input! Will try it now!! ((:

Comment: @John since it's a scool project just a little  hint for you. There is no "if loop" it's called "if statement".

Comment: @bradbury9 the reason why I added so many try and catches because if I transfer multiple files, the program will crash saying that the current file is in use and can’t be used. This would result in ‘dropped’ files with only some files being transferred while some gets dropped.

Comment: @John I was not giving advice on not using `catch` blocks. I was warning on coding `catch` block with no logic inside, because you will not know which one of them was hitted.

Comment: @bradbury9 oh I see! Thanks anyways, you sure helped a lot!! ((:

Comment: Another advise: You can use `Path.Combine()` to concatenate a path and a filename. This will automatically add a backslash when it is omitted (you don't have to worry about that. So you can replace `dest + fileName` by this: `var fullFilePath = Path.Combine(dest, fileName)` and use this variable where you like.

Comment: @stefan thanks bro!! Will use this instead!!! ((:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) for your task. Set **Filter** to your filename and subscribe for **Created** event.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher //
    {
        Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), //Set watching to MyDocuments folder
        InternalBufferSize = 32 * 1024, // set 32KB buffer size (it's a maximal size)
        Filter = "*", //Set filter to all file types
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName, //We need this notify type for watch creating files
        EnableRaisingEvents = true //Begin watcing
    };
    watcher.Created += (s, e) => //subscribe lambda to "created" event
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.FullPath} created");
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        try
        {
            File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "updated", $"{e.Name}-{Guid.NewGuid()}"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    };
    Console.ReadLine(); //waiting
}
```

I tested this code in a console application. When the application is running, try creating a file in the MyDocuments folder. The program will send a message about creating the files and copy them file in "updated" folder.

Comment: please provide relevant details in the answer